# Thymeleaf style with percent sign(%)

Tags: css, thymeleaf

I would like to express some percentage data.
So i tried like this

```
<div class="grph_wrapper">
    <div class="graph" th:style="+ height: @{(${data.RCM_CNT})}% +"></div>
</div>
```

'RCM_CNT' has 80

I would like to fill the 'grph_wrapper' class 80%

But, It didn't works, i got the error what is a `TemplateProcessingException`

How i express percent with Thymeleaf??

Comment: Have you tried this?  `<div th:style="'height:'+ ${data.RCM_CNT} +'%'">`

Comment: No I haven't  I will try